# Not able to use ehCache properly

Tags: java, ehcache

I am new to ehcache. I am not able to use ehcahe.. everytime i query through hibernate template, it hit the db only.. no caching :( what am i missing?

my **ehcache_xml::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="10000" timeToLiveSeconds="60000" overflowToDisk="false" />

    <cache name="com.abc.hibernate.model.ViewOrderSummary"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600" diskPersistent="true" />
</ehcache>
```

and which below property to use?

```
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```